# Filter multidimensional array and push in new one

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build a class schedule that takes a .csv with data for the whole semester. I have this multidimensional array, which contains the date, class, instructor, room, and notes for every day of the semester:

```
Array (
Array (
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2019-04-02 
        [2] => Study Skills 
        [3] => 371 
        [4] => Mr Teacher
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 
) 
Array ( ... )
...)
```

I managed to display the schedule for the whole semester in one table. However, ideally, I would filter out the data for each month and then push in into a new multidimensional array for the whole semester.

I was able to filter out individual months by comparing it a to hardcoded string but I obviously don't want to do that for the whole semester:

```
        $may = "05";    
        $classMay = [];

        foreach ($days as $day){
                if (strrpos($day[1], $may, -5)){
                    array_push($classMay, $day);
                }
        };
```

Is there a more efficient solution to this?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: You might look into [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: You could just extract the month number from the date using `substr($day[1], 5,2)` and use it as an index (in a similar way to AbraCadaver's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the month name from the date of each one and append the day data onto an array indexed by the month:

```
foreach($days as $day) {
    $month = date('F', strtotime($day[1]));
    $result[$month][] = $day;
}
```

Now you should have an array that looks similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [January] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2019-01-01
                    //etc
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 2019-01-02
                    //etc
                )
        )
    [February] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 2019-02-01
                    //etc
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30
                    [1] => 2019-02-02
                    //etc
                )
        )
)
```

For fun you could loop 12 months and filter on the month:

```
foreach(range(1, 12) as $m) {
    $month = date('F', strtotime($m));
    $result[$month] = array_filter($days, function($v) use($month) {
                                              return $month == date('F', strtotime($v[1]));
                                          });
}
```